# Using Azure, subdirectory will not display without https://www. being added to URL

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-web-app-service

I an inherited a website that is hosted in Azure and created using Umbraco.  I am trying to learn everything about it.  One thing I noticed is that a subdirectory we have does not display properly when you remove the https://www. from the name.

So the page will display properly if the user enters 'https://www.name.com/pagename'

If the user types 'name.com/pagename' or 'www.name.com/pagename', an error page displays that says "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Any ideas?  I'm thinking it could possibly be a problem with DNS settings as well.

Comment: If you go to just `name.com`, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it seems to only be a problem with subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess your website may enable url rewrite. By using this url rewrite, it could prevent the http url access the resource.
We could enable the urlrewrite in the webconfig file in the application.

Here is a url rewrite prevent the http url access and how 404 not found error example.

This will prevent all http access.

```
  <rule name="abort https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="1" statusDescription="1" />
                </rule>
```

So I suggest you could check your web config file in your web application.

You could find the web config by using kudu tools.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Find the Advanced Tools in DEVELOPMENT TOOLS click go.

[image]

2.Click dubug console's cmd.

[image]

3.Locate the site\wwwroot path.Find the webconfig file and click the edit button.

[image]